# divタグとasideタグの間のスタイルシートを用いて間隔を空けるためにどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: css

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

### 【質問の主旨】

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記の画像は[こちらの記事](https://e-yota.com/idle_talk/akane_club_fm_oh/)の画面下部を表しています。（ネイビー色の）タグの箇所は`div`タグで囲んでいて、「のんさん関連記事」は`asideタグ`で囲んでいます。`div`タグと`aside`タグの間隔がつまりすぎているように見えますので、両者に適当な間隔つけたいと考えています。使用しているCSSファイルにどんなセレクタとプロパティを指定すれば良いでしょうか？

### 【質問の補足】

#### 1. タグの箇所(div)について

```
.kiji-tag {
  margin-bottom: 30px; /* 追記 */
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

`margin-bottom: 30px;`を追記しましたが、タグと「のんさん関連記事」の間隔はあきませんでした。

#### 2. 「のんさん関連記事」(aside)の箇所について

```
aside .mymenu mymenu-thumb {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

上記のセレクタ・プロパティを追記しましたが、タグと「のんさん関連記事」の間隔はあきませんでした。

#### 3. コードについて

【質問の主旨】で挙げたWebサイトのコードは、master_css_20190913ブランチとしてGitHubで公開しています。

（Webサイト全体）
https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota/tree/master_css_20190913

（スタイルシート）
https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota/blob/master_css_20190913/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css

#### 4. 表示させているブランチ

現在、【質問の主旨】で挙げたURLはmasterブランチを使用して表示させています。
https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota

---

以上、ご確認よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [当該ページ](https://e-yota.com/idle_talk/akane_club_fm_oh/)を確認しましたが、 [`.kiji-tag` に適用されている CSS](https://e-yota.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css?ver=5.2.3) が、 [GitHub で公開されている CSS](https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota/blob/master_css_20190913/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css#L580) と異なるように見えます。質問者さんの適用したい CSS は、しっかりと読み込み、適用されていますか？

Comment: 質問の際に(ご自身の)GitHubをコードの参照先としてよく挙げられていますが、回答までの間にコミットが進んでいる可能性もあるため出来ればコミットハッシュを特定した方がより親切かと思います。 / 任意のページで `y` を押すとURLがハッシュ込みの状態に変わるので、こちらをコピペするとよいでしょう。 参考: [GitHub 上でコミットハッシュにもとづく URL を得る](https://developer.feedforce.jp/entry/2017/12/20/141220)

Comment: supa さん。コメントありがとうございます。私の説明が至らず恐れ入ります。

> .kiji-tag に適用されている CSS が、GitHub で公開されている CSS と異なるように見えます。

ご指摘のとおり、両者のCSSは異ります。
supaさんがおっしゃる「当該ページの.kiji-tag に適用されている CSS」は[masterブランチ](https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota/blob/master/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css)を使っています。
一方「GitHub で公開されているCSS」は、[master_css_20190913ブランチ](https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota/blob/master_css_20190913/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css#L580)を紹介しています。（続く）

Comment: （続き）supa さんへ。【質問の主旨】を言い換えると、「masterブランチのCSSを適用するとタグとのんさん関連記事がするので、master_css_20190913ブランチのようにCSSに修正しました。ですがmaster_css_20190913のCSSを適用しても両者の間隔は変わりません。両者の間隔を空けるためには、masterブランチもしくはmaster_css_20190913ブランチのCSSをどのように書き換えれば良いでしょうか？ただし、現在ブラウザ上で表示されているブランチはmasterブランチを使用しています。」となります。

Comment: cubick さん。コメントありがとうございます。

>回答までの間にコミットが進んでいる可能性もあるため出来ればコミットハッシュを特定した方がより親切かと思います。

コミットハッシュという言葉自体を初めて知りました。今回の質問に関わるCSSのmasterブランチコミットハッシュ化すると、[こんな感じ](https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota/blob/3cc6eca396090a4db728de55a925d8089fc4a9fb/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css#L580)になると思います。
また、修正を試みたものの意図通りの表示ができないmaster_css_20190913のコミットハッシュ化すると、[こんな感じ](https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota/blob/afe1b96463d5a8ef93ffc3260961ed4062a7e46b/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css#L580)になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

style.cssに下記のスタイルを記述すると、意図通りの動作ができました。

```
.mymenu mymenu-thumb { 
    margin-top: 20px; 
}
```

スタイルが当たらなかった原因はCSSの記述ではなく、ファイルのアップロードに問題がありました。
ブログサイトを公開するために使用しているサーバー（さくらのVPS）でstyle.cssを確認すると、権限が`644`でユーザー・グループ名が`root:root`になっていました。権限を`664`に、ユーザー・グループ名を`apache:一般ユーザー名`に変更すると上記のスタイルが当たるようになりました。みなさんどうもありがとうございました。